# Should web apps separate countries, or try to fit all countries in one database?

Tags: database-design, internationalization, database-schema

The obvious reason for separating is that countries have different address models, for example Canada uses 6 character postal code and USA uses 5 character zip code. This is one of many 'things' that make it difficult to create an international database to fit all cases, others being imperial units and phone number validation.

The obvious reason for keeping everything together seems quite trivial to me, and that is to avoid logistic overhead, having separate `.ca` and `.com` domains, having the respectively separate email/AWS accounts, the respective suffix for S3 buckets, deploying again for each additional country, etc.

I don't have any real world experience with this, I would really like to get advice on this matter from someone who's been through this same decision with their website.

Comment: Interesting question; you could easily keep all the data in one table, and use the country value to determine how to deal with the various column entries. But if you expect to have gazillions of records, it might be good to break them up into multiple tables (one for the US, one for Canada, one for Burkina Faso, etc.)

Comment: Not just separate tables, but separate databases and everything else. As if they were two completely independent websites that have very similar code base.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't go that far; unless, as I said, you're going to have a Googleplex of data.

Comment: But if we're serving `example.com` and `example.ca`, wouldn't that require everything to be done twice anyway? If we wanted it to be only done once, it would have to be `example.com/ca`, unless there's a way around this?